# Counting points in polygon using separate attribute values in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-statistics, point-in-polygon, count, hexagon-binning

I am trying to determine the different land surface types within a set of polygons. To do this I converted my land surface type raster layer to points.

So now I have a polygon layer (hexbins across my study area; a hexbinID is associated with each seperate hexbin) and a point layer reflecting different land surface types (e.g. smooth plains, escarpments, hills - they are also each assigned a specific number, 1-7).

What I am trying to do is count the number of specific land surface type points within each hexbin of my polygon layer. For example, if hexbin 1 has 2 points that reflect 'smooth plains' and 1 point that reflects 'hills', I would like to append that information to my hexbin column as two separate columns with counts for smooth plains and hills.

I have tried summarize within, spatial join and summary statistic but so far the furthest I have gotten is a total count of points within a hexbin, or a table where extra rows have been added in to reflect all the different points associated with each hexbin.

Is there a way to either do a count per polygon per land surface type, or to convert the extra rows into columns that reflect the counts per different land surface type for each polygon?

Answer (score 3):

1. Intersect points with polygons
2. Dissolve with statistics field unique:

> Unique—The number of unique values of the specified field will be
> counted